# F4 will not show Dashboard

Tags: keyboard, launchpad, dashboard

I just got a brand new Apple space grey wireless keyboard. Everything is great except that <kbd>F4</kbd> stopped working to launch Dashboard. Instead, <kbd>F4</kbd> launches Launchpad, something I don't use at all.

I have all the proper settings set:

- Special keys are enabled, not standard F keys
- Open Dashboard as Overlay is selected
- Changed the keyboard shortcut for Launchpad to something obscure
- Checked the keyboard shortcut for Dashboard is set to <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) The shortcut is working as you have set, i.e. F4 for Dashboard. Only since special keys are enabled (not the standard function keys), you'll have to use fn + F4 to actually invoke Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [Apple Wireless Keyboard manufactured from 2011 onwards](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201806) swaps the special Dashboard key for a special Launchpad key. I don't believe this special key function can be changed.

If you have assigned the keyboard shortcut for F4 to Dashboard, you will need to press the function(fn) key while pressing F4 to open Dashboard. Additionally, you need to make sure Dashboard is enabled in System Preferences > Mission Control as either a space or an overlay.